# variable under touch event access outside of touch start event

Tags: jquery

```
`var x=0;
$(document).on('touchstart', "#box", function (e) {
   x=1;
})
console.log(x);`
```

whenever I run this code and touch on #box it display always x=0. How to access value of x outside of touchstart event?

Comment: Please include [tag:javascript] too?

Comment: Remove keyword var